# Why does CatBoostClassifier yield different results between CPUs?

Tags: catboost

I know that CatBoost yields different results while training it on GPU and CPU due to some parameters like sub-sampling method.

Now I realized it can also not be reproduced through CPUs on the same training data and parameter settings. I used one dataset with 28 float fields and two categorical fields to train CatBoost with default parameters, except `random_state=42`. First I tried with a computer with Intel i7, then another with Intel Xeon (also Colab notebook), no train/test split. Then I used .predict_proba() method to predict probabilities of training dataset (the whole one aforementioned), the two computer gave me different results. In some cases, with different CPUs, the difference maybe at 14-16th decimal places, but I got at 1st decimal place.

If I train the model on only one computer, then save the model and use it on another, the results will be the same.

I tried to study the parameters of CatBoostClassifier but still don't know which parameter to change to make CatBoost reproducible with my data.

Does anyone face this problem? Which parameter of CatBoost do I have to change?

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vec--doc2vec--etc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism): If results are "different" each time, with _a lot_ of variation, maybe that shows problems with how you're training your model: "too little data, poorly-tuned parameters, or errors/weaknesses in the evaluation method".

Comment: The results are not "different" each time. They are the same each time I train on Intel i5-8300H, i7 7700. The differences appear when I train on Xeon(R) E5645 or use Google Colab.